# Line-Breaking algorithm (minimum raggedness) where spaces can have width different than 1.0

Tags: algorithms, optimization, dynamic-programming

The ***Divide & Conquer Algorithm for Line-Breaking*** described [here](https://xxyxyz.org/line-breaking/) is given below, both in Python and in Dart (which is similar to Java/C#).

Line-breaking is also known as "line wrap", "word wrap", or "paragraph formation", and this algorithm is used for achieving [minimum raggedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap#Minimum_raggedness).

This algorithm works, but it considers each space as having exactly `width = 1.0` .

My Question:

**How can I modify this algorithm so that it ignores spaces? In other words, make it consider spaces as having width `0.0`? (or it would also work for me if I could define any width I wanted for the spaces, including `0.0`).**

*Python Implementation:*

```
def divide(text, width):
    words = text.split()
    count = len(words)
    offsets = [0]
    for w in words:
        offsets.append(offsets[-1] + len(w))

    minima = [0] + [10 ** 20] * count
    breaks = [0] * (count + 1)

    def cost(i, j):
        w = offsets[j] - offsets[i] + j - i - 1
        if w > width:
            return 10 ** 10
        return minima[i] + (width - w) ** 2

    def search(i0, j0, i1, j1):
        stack = [(i0, j0, i1, j1)]
        while stack:
            i0, j0, i1, j1 = stack.pop()
            if j0 < j1:
                j = (j0 + j1) // 2
                for i in range(i0, i1):
                    c = cost(i, j)
                    if c <= minima[j]:
                        minima[j] = c
                        breaks[j] = i
                stack.append((breaks[j], j+1, i1, j1))
                stack.append((i0, j0, breaks[j]+1, j))

    n = count + 1
    i = 0
    offset = 0
    while True:
        r = min(n, 2 ** (i + 1))
        edge = 2 ** i + offset
        search(0 + offset, edge, edge, r + offset)
        x = minima[r - 1 + offset]
        for j in range(2 ** i, r - 1):
            y = cost(j + offset, r - 1 + offset)
            if y <= x:
                n -= j
                i = 0
                offset += j
                break
        else:
            if r == n:
                break
            i = i + 1

    lines = []
    j = count
    while j > 0:
        i = breaks[j]
        lines.append(' '.join(words[i:j]))
        j = i
    lines.reverse()
    return lines
```

*Dart implementation:*

```
class MinimumRaggedness {

  /// Given some [boxWidths], break it into the smallest possible number
  /// of lines such as each line has width not larger than [maxWidth].
  /// It also minimizes the difference between width of each line,
  /// achieving a "balanced" result.
  /// Spacing between boxes is 1.0.
  static List<List<int>> divide(List<num> boxWidths, num maxWidth) {

    int count = boxWidths.length;
    List<num> offsets = [0];

    for (num boxWidth in boxWidths) {
      offsets.add(offsets.last + min(boxWidth, maxWidth));
    }

    List<num> minimum = [0]..addAll(List<num>.filled(count, 9223372036854775807));
    List<int> breaks = List<int>.filled(count + 1, 0);

    num cost(int i, int j) {
      num width = offsets[j] - offsets[i] + j - i - 1;
      if (width > maxWidth)
        return 9223372036854775806;
      else
        return minimum[i] + pow(maxWidth - width, 2);
    }

    void search(int i0, int j0, int i1, int j1) {
      Queue<List<int>> stack = Queue()..add([i0, j0, i1, j1]);

      while (stack.isNotEmpty) {
        List<int> info = stack.removeLast();
        i0 = info[0];
        j0 = info[1];
        i1 = info[2];
        j1 = info[3];

        if (j0 < j1) {
          int j = (j0 + j1) ~/ 2;

          for (int i = i0; i < i1; i++) {
            num c = cost(i, j);
            if (c <= minimum[j]) {
              minimum[j] = c;
              breaks[j] = i;
            }
          }

          stack.add([breaks[j], j + 1, i1, j1]);
          stack.add([i0, j0, breaks[j] + 1, j]);
        }
      }
    }

    int n = count + 1;
    int i = 0;
    int offset = 0;

    while (true) {
      int r = min(n, pow(2, i + 1));
      int edge = pow(2, i) + offset;
      search(0 + offset, edge, edge, r + offset);
      num x = minimum[r - 1 + offset];

      bool flag = true;
      for (int j = pow(2, i); j < r - 1; j++) {
        num y = cost(j + offset, r - 1 + offset);
        if (y <= x) {
          n -= j;
          i = 0;
          offset += j;
          flag = false;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (flag) {
        if (r == n) break;
        i = i + 1;
      }
    }

    int j = count;

    List<List<int>> indexes = [];

    while (j > 0) {
      int i = breaks[j];
      indexes.add(List<int>.generate(j - i, (index) => index + i));
      j = i;
    }

    return indexes.reversed.toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you you try going through that article and converting each step to your version.  What's the first place where you get stuck?  I suggest you find another explanation that introduces the recurrence relation, and try to adapt the recurrence relation, and then show your work and your thoughts.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for the suggestion. Problem is, that article doesn't explain anything. It just shows different algorithms and compares their Big-O. I can't even find the Divide and Conquer algorithm in the further reading section of that article.

Comment: That might not be the best reference, then.  There are many textbooks and sources that cover this problem.

Comment: Yes, but instead of taking days to find textbooks and study this problem, I thought maybe someone here is a specialist in this kind of algorithm, and could give me an answer without going through too much trouble. Or maybe not, and that´s ok. However, this is not my area of expertise, and it's unlikely I will be able to learn enough of it to find the answer myself. Conversely, if someone asks something in my area of expertise I may give them an answer instead of just telling them to go study and show my work and thoughts.

Comment: There are no “specialists”. There are people understanding the principles of typesetting (which have become more complex because people were interested in improved quality for some time), and then it’s just a programming problem. With speed of the algorithm getting less important every year because problem sizes are not growing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the gap between any two words in the same line spans a length of $k$, instead of 1. The only change needed in the Python code would be to change the line in `def cost(i, j)` from

```
w = offsets[j] - offsets[i] + j - i - 1
```

to

```
w = offsets[j] - offsets[i] + k * (j - i - 1)
```

`def cost(i, j)` returns the minimum cost needed for placing the first $j$ words, if the last line contains the words $i + 1$ to $j$. $w$ represents the length of that last line, and `offsets[j] - offsets[i]` gives the sum of the length of the words in that line. The last term $j - i - 1$ adds the contribution of the spaces between those words. So all you have to do is tweak this last term as you need.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Works great, thank you.